# Window service unable to access remote shared folder

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created a window service in C# 4.0, I have a piece of code to read a file located at remote server. When i try to access that file, I get a error as **`"Folder does not exist c:/xxx.xx.xx.xx/sharedfolder".`**

```
    foreach (string subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories("\\xxx.xx.xx\sharedfolder"))
{

}
```

But if i run same piece of code on console application it is able to access that folder how i can get rid of it.

Comment: "**c:/x**xx.xx.xx.xx/sharedfolder", What is this **c:** in your question where does it comes form ?

Comment: Almost certainly this is a permission issue - are you running the Windows Service using the same login credentials as you are using when running the Console ? Default for Windows Services is "System" which has no rights to access network shares.

Comment: I have not given credentials, the folder is shared to everyone

Comment: @DragandDrop i am not getting how C:/ comes in the path, i get this when error is logged

Comment: it's more like what @PhillipH said it's more on permission. You can try moving it to another folder then try accessing it.

Comment: @ZweiJames but if it is able to access from console, it should be able to access from window service as well

Comment: @manojsawant - no; thats where you are going wrong. When you run in a console you have the permissions of the user who started the console application. When you run as window service, you run as Local System user - who will not have ANY permissions to ANY network share or device. You must run your service with "Logon As " as specific user. Sharing to Everyone does not grant rights to any Local System accounts.

Comment: @PhillipH Thanks, Issue is resolved, i changed the Logon to Administrator and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a service under the default *Local System Account*, will have no concept of the share. These are set up under user accounts.

**Your 2 options**

1. Run your service under a *User Account* which has those shares mapped
2. Access your share via and unc/ip address instead of the share name/drive letter. However, you will need to set the file/folder permissions accordingly.

Comment: I did change the Logon as to user ./Administrator, still i am getting same error

Comment: @manojsawant you need to set it up as the account the shares were created in